# Share link on facebook. facebook do not fetch to get description and image

Tags: facebook, sharing

I'm develop `sucsongmoi.net` (vietnamese language) and when viewer share link of site from their wall some link facebook get description and image, some link facebook could not get description and image.

eg: share `sucsognmoi.net` facebook do not get description, image 
but when i share: `sucsongmoi.net/nau-gi-hom-nay-84.html` facebook could get description and image.

I feel odd because I implement same code for this.

when I share through:
 `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.sucsongmoi.net/?a=1`
then it works. Is that facebook cache my site (như google index)? Then how can I update it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a great tool facebook provides us to deal with exactly these issues - 
Meet facebook's [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). 
 With regard to YOUR problems, you can see from [this report](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsucsongmoi.net%2Ffacebook.html) that facebook is unable to retrieve the title & url og:tags.... this is possibly due to the non-standard character set that you are using... can you try change the og:title value to something with only regular English letters? Or alternatively placing some Unicode characters instead.

Comment: here're what i correct page: add <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> and og:type=article until debug doesn't get any warning then they work. One thing border me is this any effect with SEO (google). Thanks all for you guys with your support. truly appreciate from vietnam.

Comment: Looks like the URL Debugger is now able to retrieve the information on your site =] Well done.  You might want to specify the `og:image` tag as well...

Comment: Im not an SEO expert so i can not answer you SEO question.

Comment: What's happening to this link? 
http://sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html. I also added all facebook graphic protocol but it's seem could not fetch by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see ANY `og:tags` in your source.  You can read more about Open Graph and the `og:tags` on [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). 
Basically you have to place these tags in your page so that facebook can know what information to take and display when a user shares your url.
For example :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
```

This will tell facebook about the image to use and the website name.

Comment: thanks for your kindly response. I'll follow this but does if effect to SEO of google?

Comment: it is required for the Open Graph protocol - I can not answer the SEO question because i simply do not know.

Comment: i did a test: http://sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html. and i share link through facebook but it's doesn't work. Am i wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the information that is shown when your link is posted in a Facebook status then you must add some Open Graph tags to the head section of your web page.

They are explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: What's happening to this link? sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html. I also added all facebook graphic protocol but it's seem could not fetch by facebook