# Facebook is not fetching link data

Tags: facebook, parsing

This is similar to this question but it seems that I have all the og tags in place. I am not an expert.

[Share link on facebook. facebook do not fetch to get description and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384250/share-link-on-facebook-facebook-do-not-fetch-to-get-description-and-image)

My problem:

When I paste a link on facebook, it doesn't show anything. I have checked my source and below is the page where the problem is.

```
goo.gl/gCul4E (homepage)
goo.gl/iDYzbZ (inner page)
```

Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger gives the following error:

> Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped

When I click "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", I get the following message:

> Document returned no data

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try clicking "Fetch new scrape information"?

Comment: I did. It gives the same error "Error parsin input URL,...."